# scrollView with Button at Bottom of screen

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I have to use a scroll view for the form data and a button that should be at the bottom of the screen. I have achieved it. but the problem is whenever the EditText gets focused and the keyboard is opened the button does not stay at the bottom of the screen it comes just above the android keyboard. I want it to be there at the bottom even when the keyboard is opened or not.

[image]
[image]

I have tried the `android:fillViewport="true"` with scroll view but it does not give a proper output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/lout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/fimg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/addimg" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/vsubcusine"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
            >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/add_food_title"
                            style="@style/textbox"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Title for Food"
                            android:inputType="text"

                            />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/vcusine"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="cusine"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp">

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/cusine"
                            style="@style/textbox"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="#fff"
                            android:padding="10dp" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp">


                        <RadioGroup
                            android:id="@+id/isveg"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/veg"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:text="Veg" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/nonveg"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="2"

                                android:text="Non-Veg" />

                        </RadioGroup>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/vfprice"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/fprice"
                            style="@style/textbox"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:hint="price"
                            android:inputType="number" />


                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/t"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/foodadd"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:text="ADD FOOD"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout as your parent.

Comment: @tahsinRupam this solution does not works it does not display button on screen at all

Comment: It needs some customization also, I can add requiring modification with screenshot if you like.

Comment: @tahsinRupam why not ? it will be helpfull thanks is advance

Comment: Alright wait a moment please.

Comment: Check my answer, sorry for late response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **manifest**, Just Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your corresponding activity tag:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

**Output**:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's my pleasure. :)